# how to retrieve data from json in json

Tags: php, json, yii, yii1.x

I have following code in my contoller:

```
public function actionForm($id)
    {
        $jsonfile=ChForms::model()->findByPk($id);
        $decodedJson=json_decode($jsonfile->json, true);
        var_dump($decodedJson);
        return $decodedJson;
    }
```

Here json ( in $jsonfile->json) is name of the field in ChForms.
When I wrote  `var_dump($decodedJson);, it showed the data below:

```
array(38) { ["name"]=> string(10) "membership" ["view"]=> string(14) "pdf/membership" ["phone"]=> string(5) "22222"
```

I am going to display it in the following way:

```
name: membership
view: pdf/membership
phone: 22222
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [foreach()](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php):

```
foreach ($decodedJsonas as $key => $value) {
        echo "$key: $value \n";
    }
```

You can see how it works below:

[PHP Compiler](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/de48df6091bd41c8045304cced40297516d8ce17)